# Query that determines the % of right swipes per day that resulted in a match

Tags: sql, join

How to find the % of right swipes per day that resulted in a match. A match occurs when user A right swipes on user B, and user B right swipes on user A.

Here is the sample data:

```
swiping_user_id   swiped_on_user_id      swipe_at            swipe_type
1 1958315            7247259         2015-03-15 00:01:05      right
2 5823050            8732832         2014-06-10 05:12:05      left
3 7948392            6767291         2015-08-10 12:45:01      right
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server? MySql?

Comment: Thanks for the solution Michal. It was one of the questions from the practice test. So, any type of RDBMS is fine. I just wanted to see the logic of the query.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you number of swipes that resulted in a match:

```
select count(*) matchedSwipes
from SwipeTable st1
join SwipeTable st2 on 
st1.swiping_user_id = st2.swiped_on_user_id and
st2.swiping_user_id = st1.swiped_on_user_id and
st1.swipe_type = st2.swipe_type
where s1.swipe_type = 'right'
```

Then just get the total count of swipes and divide number of matched swipes by that total count.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ratio, then you can do:

```
select count(*) as num_right_swipes,
       count(st2.swipe_type) as num_matches,
       count(st2.swipe_type) * 1.0 / count(*) as ratio
from SwipeTable st1 left join
     SwipeTable st2
     on st2.swiping_user_id = st1.swiped_on_user_id and
        st2.swiped_user_id = st1.swiping_on_user_id and
        st2.swipe_type = st1.swipe_type
where s2.swipe_type = 'right';
```

This assumes that the swipes are unique (i.e. not two "right" swipes for person A to person B).  If this is not the case, you should ask a *new* question and explain how to handle duplicates.